# Show that a) $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{z}}=z$. b) Show that if $\vert z \vert \lt 1$ then $ \vert Re (2 + \bar z + z^3)\vert \le 4$.

Tags: complex-numbers, solution-verification

Show that
a) $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{z}}=z$.
b) Show that if $\vert z \vert \lt 1$ then $ \vert Re (2 + \bar z + z^3)\vert \le 4$.

My attempt:

a)  $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{z}}= \frac{1}{z^{-1}} = (z^{-1})^{-1} = z$
b)  $\vert Re(2 + \bar z + z^3)\vert \le 4$

$1 \gt \vert z \vert \ge \vert Re(z) \vert$ and $\vert Re (\bar z) \vert = \vert Re(z) \vert \lt 1$ and $\vert z \vert \lt 1 \to \vert z^3 \vert \lt 1$ and $ \vert Re(2) \vert = 2$  then $\vert Re(2 + \bar z + z^3)\vert \lt 4$

I think a) is correct but in b) this was as far as I could get.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Show that $\frac 1{\frac 1z} = z$? In what context? Have you learned the definition of a field and field axioms? Are we allowed to say that $z \cdot 1 = z$ for all $z$? That $1 = \frac zz$ for all $z\ne 0$?  You say $(z^{-1})^{-1} = z$ but how do you know that is true.  What *is* your definition $z^k$? and what axioms are you assuming? The question is very "basic" and as that what it *means* and how you prove it will depend on your definitions and axioms...[FWIW I'd do $\frac 1{\frac 1z}=\frac 1{\frac 1z}\cdot 1=\frac 1{\frac 1z}\cdot \frac zz=\frac {1\cdot z}{\frac 1z\cdot z}=\frac z1 = z$]

Comment: I would argue from a purely algebraic argument that the *definition* of $\frac 1w$ is the unique solution to  $k$ so that $k\cdot w = 1$.  So $\frac 1{\frac 1z}$ must be the unique number $k$ so that $k\cdot \frac 1z= 1$.  However $\frac 1z$ is itselfed defined and the unique number $m$ solution to  $m\cdot z = 1$ so $\frac 1z\cdot z=z\cdot \frac 1z=1$ by definition.  $k = z$ is the unique solution to $k\cdot \frac 1z = 1$.  So $\frac 1{\frac 1z} = z$... But I doubt that is the definition or approach you text is taking.

Comment: I guess the real question *I* need to know in order to help *you* is I need to know exactly how *your* text defined $\frac wz$.  Just apply that and it'll work but if I don't know how your specific text defined it, I won't be able to do anything.  [Lest I sound *too* harsh though.  ***If*** your text has proven that $(z^a)^b = z^{ab}$ (and specified $a,b$ may be negative) then your solution is *PERFECT*... the point I'm trying to make though, is for "basic" problems one needs axioms and definitions in order to do *anything*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A is correct.  An alternative way of showing A is

$\displaystyle z^{-1} = \frac{\overline{z}}{|z|^2}.$

Then 
$\displaystyle \frac{1}{z^{-1}} = \left[\frac{\overline{z}}{|z|^2}\right]^{-1} = \left[\overline{z}\right]^{-1} \times \left[\frac{1}{|z|^2}\right]^{-1} $

$\displaystyle =~ \frac{z}{|\overline{z}|^2} \times |z|^2 = z \times \frac{|z|^2}{|\overline{z}|^2} = z.$

---

For B:

A case could be made that your work is actually valid and (virtually) complete, as is.

That is, you are relying on the idea, which is true, that

$|\text{Re}(z_1)| + |\text{Re}(z_2)| \geq |\text{Re}(z_1) + \text{Re}(z_2)| = |\text{Re}(z_1 + z_2)|.$

An alternative approach to part B is:

$|z| < 1 \implies |\overline{z}| < 1~$ and $~|z^3| = |z|^3 < 1.$

Using the triangle inequality, you have in general that

$|z_1 + z_2 + z_3| \leq |z_1| + |z_2| + |z_3|.$

Therefore, you have that

$|2 + \overline{z} + z^3| < 4.$

You also have that in general, for any complex $z$, 
that $|\text{Re}(z)| \leq |z|.$

Therefore, $|\text{Re}(2 + \overline{z} + z^3)| < 4.$